# Java - Executing .sh Files in Centos

Tags: java, centos, sh

I've been tearing my hair out for hours about this problem, but I can't seem to get these start scripts to work. What the start scripts are supposed to do is launch a Java server with a screen attached, but for some reason it won't launch.

It doesn't throw any errors in Java, so it's finding the file correctly.

Code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/home/Network/" + name + "/" + name.toLowerCase() + ".sh");
pb.start();
```

SH Script:

```
screen -S ServerID java -jar -Xms1536M -Xmx1536M server.jar
```

EDIT: Solved my problem. For anybody curious and doing something similar, you should use screen -dmS to launch it in daemon mode, and that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem, I used -dmS inside of the SH script instead of -S, since that starts it as a daemon instead.

```
screen -S ServerID java -jar -Xms1536M -Xmx1536M server.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/home/Network/" + name + "/" + name.toLowerCase() + ".sh run");
```

or "start" or whatever commands your script accepts.

.sh are scripts, not processes.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I solved my problem, but ProcessBuilder is a lot better anyway, so thanks

Comment: You should add your solution to the question, and mark it as an answer for completions sake.

Comment: Okay and I can set it as the answer in two days.